# webstorm IntelliSense not showing ng-disabled for button

Tags: angularjs, webstorm, simulator

I got AngualrJS plugin installed and enabled, and set angular.js to javascript lib, but there is no `ng-disabled` code completion pops up when I want to add it to button attribute, but it shows the code completion when add to other elements like input.

This code works fine but still it's annoying that webstorm display such pop-up like this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've noticed I have the same behavior. Anyway ng-disabled still works fine in the browser for me.

Comment: Please have a look at the related issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-11206#comment=27-1026850